# Git - Do colours mean something in vi when I commit?

Tags: git, syntax-highlighting, commit, vi

I'm using Git Bash on Windows and, when I run `git commit`, the vi editor opens to allow me writing a Commit note. I noticed that the first row of the text I write is yellow (although not all of it, only the first 30 or 40 characters), the second is white on a red background and from the 3rd onwards they are gray. Does this colour coding mean anything, or is it just some sort of weird glitch? I come from an SVN background, where Commit comment was pure text and I wasn't expecting this "rainbow". :)

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: I always just do `git commit -m "Message"` from Git Bash.

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure (I've wondered about this too -- here's [what it looks like in Vim](http://jsfiddle.net/VAVeX/)), but I think the idea is that the first 30-40 characters of the first line is the message you will see if you are skimming through commits (or viewing a pretty version of the log) and you want to get across your important text there.  The specific colors don't mean anything though.

Comment: @knowah, that's not good advice. If you use command line commit messages, you usually end up writing as short a message as possible, especially avoiding newlines. On the other hand, spawning an editor for the message makes you feel relaxed with writing as big a message as you feel like.

Comment: @Shahbaz I guess you're right -- I had learned git using the `-m` way and didn't realize that it would open an editor if it was left off. My work is mostly maintenance so the short messages usually are enough. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Shahbaz That's true, in fact I write quite a bit of stuff in commit messages, to keep track of what I changed and, most importantly, why. This is crucial for refactoring, as one may change stuff and then wonder why he did it a few hours later. It happens to me all the time...

Comment: The first line is used in `git shortlog` or `git log --oneline` (and their friends). This colour just a hints this line is differenet.

Comment: Newlines in conjunction with `-m`option are possible (at least in bash). Just don't close the string with `"` until you're done. In fact I just did and then came here 'cause I `amend`ed and also wondered about the colors :) Anyway of course @Shahbaz is right about meaningful messages!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Vi is giving you a hint about "properly" formatting your commit message.

While there is no specific enforcement of one message style w.r.t. another, "[traditionally](http://git-scm.com/book/ch5-2.html#_commit_guidelines)" Git commit messages are structured this way:

- A short title describing the changeset (usually less than 50-60 characters);
- One blank line;
- A more complete description of the commit, optionally divided in paragraphs with other blank lines.

The last paragraph is usually used for "metadata" entries, like `Signed-off-by:`.

So, in your case, Vi is probably warning you that the first line is a a little longer than usual and that you did not leave a blank line after it (I say "probably" because I do not use Vi, so I am not sure about it).

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's good to have a confirmation. I now use the first line as a reference note, I skip the second (mainly because I hate writing on red, too bright) and then I fill the rest what anything I like. I'm a very basic user of Git, but I'm learning (in a JIT basis, obviously). :)