# Configure git commit editor colors

Tags: git, vim

What is the parameter to configure the color of the first line (and the body text) of the commit message editor of git? (In case that matters, I am using vim as an editor).

I have found many related resources, but none of them gave the option to specify this color.
(For the records, the most relevant hits were the following:

- https://gist.github.com/rab/4067067
- [Git - Do colours mean something in the editor that opens when I commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083754)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266)

I am beginning to suspect that this option has to be configured somewhere else (e.g. in bash or in vim)...

Comment: When you try to commit, default editor for this show up for you to edit messages, i guess vim in your case. So you must search answer to this question in vim (.vimrc) settings. Your question has nothing to do with git itself as i suppose.

Comment: I assume you're looking for something as [described here](https://kparal.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/git-tip-of-the-day-syntax-highlighting-for-commit-messages/) (where it is also noted that the default editor was `vi`, not `vim`).

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138148/make-vim-stop-splitting-my-git-commit-messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the color of the title when you are editing the commit message in vim, add following code to `~/.vimrc`

```
au FileType gitcommit
 \ hi gitcommitSummary ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=red
```

other highlight option can be found by typing `:hi` in vim command, or from following url

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/gitcommit.vim

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer to my original question. For the records, in the end, I just added the setting "set background=light" to .vimrc, so the default colors for this scheme are fine.

Comment: @Attilio this did it for me too! Thank you for this, nothing that I tried in the past worked.

Answer (score 5):

What I was missing was a `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable. (Can also be set as `core.editor` in `git config`.) When I set that to `/usr/bin/vim`, the colors showed up in my commit editor session.

Comment: The trick was to use `editor = /usr/bin/vim` instead of `editor = vim`. :facepalm:

Answer (score 4):

As the syntax script for the `gitcommit` filetype properly uses `:hi def link`, you can simply overwrite any of its highlightings in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:hi gitcommitSummary ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=red
```

No `:au FileType gitcommit` (as in @ymonad's answer) is necessary.