# How to show different colors in files list when I filling git commit message in vim

Tags: git, vim, syntax-highlighting, git-commit, color-scheme

when I'm filling commit messsage, I can see the files list, but they are same color (new/modify/del)

I'm asking **file list** highlighting, no **message** highlighting, not duplicate question of [Configure git commit editor colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826956)

I can only get the tag name is `gitcommitSelectedFile`, how to distinguish them ?

the first picture is in my vim, the second one is in vs code

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure git commit editor colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826956/configure-git-commit-editor-colors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change by modify `gitcommit.vim`

You can find your `gitcommit.vim` in `syntax/` dir.

> you can easily find vim dir by `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` inside your vim.

Inside `gitcommit.vim`, you have to find gruop you want to change.

In my setting, it's `gitcommitSelectedType`. Here's gitcommitSelectedType match - it use `\t\@<=[[:lower:]][^:]*[[:lower:]]:` for matching `modified:` and `new file:` in commit template.

```
syn match   gitcommitSelectedType   "\t\@<=[[:lower:]][^:]*[[:lower:]]: "he=e-2 contained containedin=gitcommitComment nextgroup=gitcommitSelectedFile skipwhite
```

For simple example, I clear `gitcoomitSelectedType` and add new match for `gitcommitNew` and `gitcommitModified`. (simple match for example. You can use regex for your own)

```
syn clear gitcommitSelectedType
" match for new file and modified
syn match gitcommitNew  "\t\@<=new file: " contained containedin=gitcommitComment nextgroup=gitcommitSelectedType skipwhite
syn match   gitcommitModified   "\t\@<=modified: "he=e-2    contained containedin=gitcommitComment nextgroup=gitcommitModified skipwhite

" give other color type for these group
hi link gitcommitNew    Type
hi link gitcommitModified   Special
" add two groups we made to gitcommitSelected
syn region  gitcommitSelected   start=/^# Changes to be committed:/ end=/^#$\|^#\@!/ contains=gitcommitHeader,gitcommitHead,gitcommitSelectedType,gitcommitNew,gitcommitModified fold
```

Maybe there's better solution - not using group but using exception after gitcommitSelectedType - but I don't know how. Maybe you can find it.

#### Before

[image: Before change color]

#### After

[image]

### ADD

Also, it will added for future. Check [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-git/pull/58)

Comment: thank you! I made one too, base on your 
suggest https://gist.github.com/zhengkai/6edd09b813c4b9a3fc634584e37d6ad9 
this version change filename color too